# Php natsort by 2 dimensions array

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, natsort

I've the following sql: `SELECT s.flat, s.name FROM source s`.  Flat may contains flats with delimiter like 1/5 or 1/2, and I can not use numeric fileld in this case. In the result I get sorting like this:

```
1 Bob, 
10 Joe, 
11 Tim, 
12 Lisa, 
2 Ira, 
21 Tom,
```

How can I use `natsort()` method for 'flats' part with saving 'name' part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do a pretty good job of it:

```
SELECT s.flat, s.name FROM source s ORDER BY CAST(s.flat AS UNSIGNED)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29e54d/3/0)